# Запуск программы на удаленном компьютере с сетевого запароленного диска

Tags: cmd

Не могу понять как это точно надо сделать.

Нужно чтобы этот файл (.iso) начал запускать непосредственно перед глазами пользователя.

Я вижу это так.

Подсоединяемся к компьютеру пользователя через через админа домена:

psexec \domaincomp -h -u domain\admin -p adminpass cmd

Дальше видимо надо через net use добавить сетевой диск пользователю, и потом с него уже открыть этот файл. Но вопрос как это сделать из под пользователя, ведь я уже залогинен под админом домена.

Прошу помощи с этим.

Comment: мне кажется, уместнее было бы спросить [на ServerFault](http://serverfault.com/)

Comment: `net use x: \\server\resource\folder password /user:username@domain`

Comment: @Akina эта команда подключит сетевой диск с использованием этих учетных данных или этот диск появится у данного пользователя?

Comment: команда runas не работает ?

Comment: @MikeV. как ее использовать в связке с net use?

Comment: @Сергей Эта команда подключает сетевой диск к локальному драйву с использованием прав указанной учётной записи в сеансе текущей учётной записи. В твоём случае - в сеансе админа с правами юзера.

Comment: @Сергей ну пробовать, как еще. ведь сеть у вас под руками..

Comment: @MikeV. спасибо)) но я поэтому и пишу, потому что не справился.

Comment: @Akina вот. А можно как то юзеру подключит на этом же компе. Я могу как админ домена это сделать, или нет? Только не групповыми политиками, а прям сию минуту.

Comment: @Сергей попробуйте runas /netonly /user:computer\username cmd.exe

Comment: @MikeV. Запустил со своего компа, без подключение через psexec. Что мне это дает? Если пропишу net use будет установлен диск у пользователя?

Comment: @Сергей у себя не надо запускать, пробуйте в сессии psexec на чужом компе

Comment: @MikeV. почему то после ввода runas запрашивает пароль, но не дает ввести, сразу выбрасывает на новую строку.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52930/discussion-between--and-mike-v).